# Can this DVD Player Play Modern File Formats?

Tags: tv, mp4

I'm trying to get a TV with a Sony DVP-S560D CD/DVD Player going. They would like play some videos from the internet on it.

Will the Sony DVP-S560D play MP4 files, AVI files, video CDs or do these videos need to be transformed into a traditional DVD?
The DVD player was probably built around the year 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I’m afraid it [does not support](http://www.videohelp.com/dvdplayers/sony-dvp-s560d/437) any audio or video files natively. Aside from (MPEG-2) DVD videos, it only supports [VCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcd) (MPEG-1) and [SVCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVCD) (MPEG-2), so you will need to convert your video files to one of those.

Comment: Synetech, your answer was very helpful, thank you.
I opened up a new and related question at
(http://superuser.com/questions/388076/how-to-make-a-dvd-with-ubuntu-k3b-and-an-mpeg2-file)